# Calcular columna con Capital en una inversión sin bucle y con cálculo vectorizado

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectores

Partiendo del siguiente Dataframe con las cotizaciones o precio de cierre de IBM a fin de mes y al que le he añadido una columna donde voy a ir aportando 100€ en cada cuatrimestre (es decir el último día del mes en el que está la inversión):

```
datos = {'IBM': [137.62,124.79,131.03,151.45,145.94,153.74,\
             151.78,160.62,158.88,158.85,153.69,162.22,165.99] }
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, index='dic-15 ene-16 feb-16 mar-16 abr-16 may-16 \
             jun-16 jul-16 ago-16 sep-16 oct-16 nov-16 dic-16'.split())
df['inversión'] = ([100] + [0] *3) * 3 + [0]
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento calcular una nueva columna 'Capital' que me indique el capital que tengo acumulado al final de cada mes.

Lo he conseguido con un bucle:

```
capital = []
for i in range(13):
    if i == 0:
        capital.append(df['inversión'][i])
    else:
        capital.append((capital[-1]*df['IBM'][i]/df['IBM'][i-1])+df['inversión'][i])
df['Capital'] = capital
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si se podría hacer con cálculo vectorial en lugar de con bucle.

He intentado:

```
df['Capital2'] = 100  
df['Capital2'] = df['Capital2'] * df['IBM'][i] / df['IBM'].shift(1) + df['inversión']
df
```

Pero me devuelve un NnN en la primera fila y el resto de datos no están bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar DataFrame.cumsum()
En la documentación de pandas tienes los parámetros, argumentos y ejemplos:
[Documentación Pandas Dataframe - cumsum-](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html#pandas.DataFrame.cumsum)

En tu caso concreto, basta con incluir esta línea justo después de que hayas creado la columna 'inversión':

```
df['capital2'] = df['IBM']*(df['inversión']/df['IBM']).cumsum()
```

Esto lo que hace es calcular el número de títulos que obtienes después de cada aportación, sumándolos a los que ya tenías, y después lo multiplicas por el valor de la acción (IBM) en cada momento.

El resultado es este:

```
           IBM  inversión    capital2     Capital
dic-15  137.62        100  100.000000  100.000000
ene-16  124.79          0   90.677227   90.677227
feb-16  131.03          0   95.211452   95.211452
mar-16  151.45          0  110.049411  110.049411
abr-16  145.94        100  206.045633  206.045633
may-16  153.74          0  217.058076  217.058076
jun-16  151.78          0  214.290847  214.290847
jul-16  160.62          0  226.771615  226.771615
ago-16  158.88        100  324.314994  324.314994
sep-16  158.85          0  324.253756  324.253756
oct-16  153.69          0  313.720867  313.720867
nov-16  162.22          0  331.132794  331.132794
dic-16  165.99          0  338.828334  338.828334
```